# Nativescript Angular - Using application events

Tags: android-intent, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After struggling for a few hours, I hope I can find someone who understands this. Nativescript offers support for Application events for Angular + Typescript:

http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/application-management.html

However, I do not understand where I should add these. The example from the website shows the following code:

```
import application = require("application");
application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args: application.ApplicationEventData) {
    if (args.android) {
        // For Android applications, args.android is an android.content.Intent class.
        console.log("Launched Android application with the following intent: " + args.android + ".");
    } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
        // For iOS applications, args.ios is NSDictionary (launchOptions).
        console.log("Launched iOS application with options: " + args.ios);
    }
});

...

application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

How can I use this within my Angular application? To me it feels like this isn't actually code for the Angular version, but perhaps I'm missing something.

I have tried importing the application and adding it the ngOnInit of my main AppComponent:

```
ngOnInit() {
    application.on(application.launchEvent, function (args: application.ApplicationEventData) {
        if (args.android) {
            // For Android applications, args.android is an android.content.Intent class.
            console.log("Alert something"); // : " + args.android + ".");
        } else if (args.ios !== undefined) {
            // For iOS applications, args.ios is NSDictionary (launchOptions).
            console.log("Launched iOS application with options: " + args.ios);
        }
        console.log('launch detected')
    });

    console.log('application initiated');
}
```

Although I do not get any errors, I only get to see the application initiated message. Any idea on how I can use the mentioned android args?

**Update:**
In the end it was much easier than expected, please see the code I used to fix this:

```
import app = require('application');
import "reflect-metadata";
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

app.on(app.launchEvent, function (args: app.ApplicationEventData) {
    // on launch code
});

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add application event functions to main.ts or app.ts file and before line with Bootstrap

```
import app = require('application');
import "reflect-metadata";
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

app.on(app.launchEvent, function (args: app.ApplicationEventData) {
    // on launch code
});

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Comment: There is no application.start in my angular project, all I see is: nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent);

Comment: I'll mark this answer as the right answer, because in the end it helped me solve it. Thank you!